# Is it possible to run one MySQL instance on multiple Artifactory instances

Tags: java, mysql, nexus, artifactory

I'm running into a use case where we would like to run multiple Artifactory OSS instances for caching artifacts from a master Nexus server.

However, caching artifacts on local filestore isn't a good option because there is limited Disk space, so we're thinking about using a single MySQL server with cache-fs on the Artifactory instances' hosts.

Have anyone have any experience with connecting multiple Artifactory instances to one MySQL instance? If possible, what are the caveats and how do you circumvent the problem(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear. Do you want to store your artifacts as blobs in the database? if so the answer is a big NO NO! Do not do a blob storing of files on MySQL. 
As for your question, you can set several Artifactory's into a single DB, just create and direct them to a different schema.